# Second-order logic and Russell's Paradox

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, paradoxes

I know that in first-order logic the following holds [see e.g. George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory. Volume 2: Set Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=nparMXao59QC&pg=PA121) (2003), page 121] :

> $\vdash \lnot ∃y \ ∀x \ [A(x,y) \leftrightarrow \lnot A(x,x)]$,

for any formula $A(x,y)$.

I assume that this result "transfers" to second-order logic.

A simple instance of s-o *comprehension schema* is:

> $∃X \ ∀x \ [\varphi(x) \leftrightarrow X(x)]$

where $X$ may not occur free in $\varphi(x)$.

Thus, with $\varphi(y) := ∀x \ [A(x,y) \leftrightarrow \lnot A(x,x)]$, we get:

> > $\vdash ∃X \ ∀y \ [∀x \ (A(x,y) \leftrightarrow \lnot A(x,x)) \leftrightarrow X(y)]$.

May we "cook together" the two results to conclude with ?:

> $\vdash ∃X \ \lnot ∃y \ X(y)$

---

*Note* : motivated also by this [Wiki's talk-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3ASecond-order_logic#second_order_logic_and_russell.27s_paradox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do that, but I don't think it buys you anything that you don't get by letting $\varphi(y)$ be any odd contradiction such as $A(y)\land\neg A(y)$.

Comment: Right, thanks; it looks to me like a derivation of the *empty set*, but I'm not sure that it is formally correct.

Comment: @Mauro: Yes, $\exists X\neg\exists y\;X(y)$ is just a second-order formulation of "an empty set exists".

Comment: The usual way to get the empty set from comprehension is to use a formula that is unsatisfiable, e.g. $(\exists X)(\forall n)[n \in X \leftrightarrow n \not = n]$. You could certainly replace $n \not = n$ with $(\forall z)[A(x,z) \leftrightarrow \lnot A(x,y)]$. @Mauro ALLEGRANZA

Comment: @CarlMummert: I think that's what I'm saying too, right? Except that I'm using $A(y)\land \neg A(y)$ instead of $y\ne y$ as the "usual" choice of unsatisfiable property. (Which was an attempt not to depend on a primitive notion of equality).

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to support the explanation. @Henning